# LazyColumn items draw on top of each other

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was using Jetpack Compose version 1.0.0-alpha01 and LazyColumnFor to display some items in a list. After updating to 1.0.0-beta06 I noticed that LazyColumnFor had been deprecated in favor of LazyColumn. After migrating however, the items in the list draw on top of each other instead of being listed vertically with some spacing in between.

What's odd here is that the Preview renders the items as expected, while the app installed on the device(s) does not.

Here's the activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp)
            val boldStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
            ComposeListTestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                        items(listOf("Row1", "Row2")) { day ->
                            Text(
                                text = day,
                                style = boldStyle,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp),
                                color = Color.Green
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And here's the preview:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    val textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp)
    val boldStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
    ComposeListTestTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
        ) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
                items(listOf("Row1", "Row2")) { day ->
                    Text(
                        text = day,
                        style = boldStyle,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp),
                        color = Color.Green
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Unfortunately I haven't been able to get the new layout inspector to work on any of my devices, or I suspect I could've seen some clues as to why this happens.

ComposeListTestTheme:

```
@Composable
fun ComposeListTestTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Comment: Post a screen pls

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I've added screens from the preview and the device.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked fine :/

Comment: Your code should work

Comment: Oh thanks for testing it. I wonder if I've run into a platform dependency bug then (though I thought Compose is decoupled). I'm running this on an Android Things (API Level 28) device, though I did get the same behavior on a Pixel 2 running R. I'll debug further and post back if I find an answer..

Comment: The sample app layout looks alright on Android R but not on Android Things (API 27, not 28). I get the same issue when deploying the preview to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened because the app was not hardware accelerated. This was fixed in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187853238.

Comment: Note that this is still broken on API 30 & API 31